# Hierarchical Data in MySQL with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to build a hierarchical list in a website. There are four levels of information:

Categories > Types > Sections > Topics

the id of category is a foreign key for types, the id for types is a foreign key for sections, the id for sections is the foreign key for topics.

This structure seemed necessary as there are pages for each of those four kinds of levels. The pages each display the information in each part as well as the children parts.

Meaning, you could visit `http://localhost/community/category.php?id=1` (or any number between 0 and 20ish) and `http://localhost/community/types.php?id=3` etc for each of the other two kinds of information as well.

Could i build a hierarchical list with this sort of structure or would i have to do it like  a traditional hierarchical mysql structure?

Comment: I've posted this link more than once before: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Dagon Which method do you feel is the best for general use??

Comment: I have always used the The Adjacency List Model; as long as one of the listed limitations is not going to be an issue with your particular data set.

Comment: ill look into that one, time to completely rebuild the structure of my site haha. thanks though

Comment: @Dagon, if you put that comment as an answer to the question ill give you the points haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted this link more than once before: mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql
...

I have always used the The Adjacency List Model; as long as one of the listed limitations is not going to be an issue with your particular data set